# What to do when multiple issues covered by multiple answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, multiple-answers

### Research

I can find meta posts addressing multiple answers where *both* to fix an issue but in different ways, or multiple responders with (effectively) the same answer, but not my issue.

### Issue

I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37425206/using-ngoninit-instead-of-a-constructor-input-undefined) and it got two separate answers. In the end I had to use *both* to resolve the issue, making one no more 'correct' than the other, and making them entirely distinct.

What are the guidelines in this case, since I can't accept both?

Comment: Write a community wiki answer that shows how you combined them to solve the problem? Then you neither: a) accept one over the other; nor b) appear to be trying to "profit" from their posters' efforts.

Comment: @Liam trawling for a badge?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution might be to up vote both answers, and then post another answer that combines both of them (as [jonsharpe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323787/what-to-do-when-multiple-issues-covered-by-multiple-answers#comment348307_323787) said).

If you mark it as Community Wiki, it will not appear as if you are trying to "steal" the rep. You should link to their answers to not only attribute your sources, but additionally, it will encourage others to up vote the other answers too.

---

Also note that accepting your own answer doesn't give you the +15 rep, and it's not pinned to the top (it will move up or down based on its score vs. the other answers' scores).